# Nagios map change host color on service down

Tags: monitoring, nagios

i'm running a nagios setup for checking 150+ hosts, some of those hosts have services running on them that i want to check.

i now have all the hosts visable on the map with the correct parent relations.

but now i want the host to change color when one of its services goes down so that i know something is going on.
how would i go about doing that?

i have looked at the nagios documentation but to no avail

i'm running nagios core 4.1.1 with the nagios plugins 2.1.1